# What is an "intermezzo from the dusky elm's trunk"?

Tags: poetry, uyghur-language, tahir-hamut

*Phone Call* by Tahir Hamut (full text on [Words Without Borders](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/august-2019-chinese-poetry-phone-call-tahir-hamut-joshua-l-freeman)) contains the following line:

> An intermezzo from the dusky elm’s trunk
> fans the spirit lamp into a bonfire

I'm somewhat confused by the first line, though; what is an "intermezzo" in this context, and why is it "from the dusky elm's trunk"?